# my sinatra website to talk to twilio

Tags: xml, sinatra, twilio

Sinatra wraps all the views in the layout.erb wherever you placed <%= yield %> in that file. This is great if you are only serving html pages to browsers. BUT
We are writting an app that also requires to talk to Twilio via XML. Challenge: all our outputs were being sent out wrapped in a `<!DOCTYPE/html>`.

We managed to bypass the layout.erb by specifying layout: false in our action.erb file.

```
post '/incoming' do
  content_type 'text/xml'
  @message = "this is working"
 erb :'/incoming.xml', layout: false
end
```

I am sure there is a 'better' way of having Sinatra serve the xml content and would appreciate very much your help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation/question correctly you are looking for a cleaner way of serving XML (Twilio's TwiML in this case) from Sinatra. If that's the case, I recommend checking out the [Sinatra::Builder module](http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/api/classes/Sinatra/Builder.html). This module will allow you to dynamically build the TwiML right within the route. It also supports templates if you want to use a templated approach.

Full documentation for Builder can be found on [Builder's RubyForge page](http://builder.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Thank you Brent! This is exactly what I was looking for. Twilio is just one example of requiring to communicate with an API via xml and I did not want to use their gem just to keep

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the twilio-ruby gem https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby to render the Twiml from your action like this:

```
post '/incoming' do
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say "This is working"
  end

  response.text
end
```

That will render the proper Twiml doc that twilio is expecting.